# Why is my longest array value function in Javascript not working? Newbie help please

Tags: javascript

This is my first week learning Javascript so this is very new to me. How can I call this function and get it to work. Here is my code.

```
var ninjaTurtles = ["Leonardo", "Donatello", "Michelangelo", "Raphael"];

function longest(strings) {
    var longestName = strings[0];

    for (i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (strings[i].length > longestName.length) {
            longestName = strings[i];
        }
    }

    return longestName;
}

longest(ninjaTurtles);
```

Don't really know what the hell I am doing please help.

EDIT: Okay so I got it to work thanks your help, appreciate it! Now, If i wanted to tweak this same code to get the shortest word out of the array, what do I need to change?

Comment: It tells me `Michelangelo` is longest, so it seems to work...? Two areas for improvement, though. **(1)** Declare `var i` within the function to prevent accidents where you ruin somebody else's `i` and **(2)** What happens if someone calls `longest([])` with an empty array?

Comment: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xS6Mu/) works OK

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Okay when I ran it on my webpage the alert box simply did not pop up which is why I was confused. After looking at that fiddle i realized my last line of code should look like this:alert(longest( ninjaTurtles ));

Comment: You have to do something with the return value - that last line calls the function but then throws away the value it returned.  Needs to be another `return` or a `console.log` or `alert` or something.

Comment: Since you're new to JavaScript, here's a piece of advice that will help you endlessly: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could turn that entire thing into a one-liner that also handles empty arrays and doesn't pollute the global variable scope using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
return strings.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b }, '')
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/xS6Mu/2/

Comment: Worth noting this is not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: @porfuse On the page I linked to is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility) that adds `reduce` to the `Array` prototype for browsers not supporting it natively. Also, IE8 is now over 3 years old and 3 major versions behind the current (11). It should not be supported